# OS Maps API – WMTS map (EPSG:27700), Point and Route layers fail to draw

Tags: openlayers, maps, layers-failed-to-draw

Can anyone help a Nube? I'm learning OpenLayers using OS Maps. I am using WMTS(EPSG:27700) projection. The OS map displays, however, point and route layers do not, although I have successfully got both to display on a WMTS map (EPSG:3857) projection.  Below is my code:-

```
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://labs.os.uk/public/os-api-branding/v0.3.0/os-api-branding.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.0/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/os-transform.js"></script>
    <script>
       var apiKey = 'MyAPIKey';
       var serviceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/wmts';

       var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
       var map;

       // Setup the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) projection.
       proj4.defs("EPSG:27700", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");
       ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

       fetch(serviceUrl + '?key=' + apiKey + '&service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities&version=2.0.0')
         .then(response => response.text())
         .then(text => {
            var result = parser.read(text);
            var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
               layer: 'Leisure_27700',
               matrixSet: 'EPSG:27700'
            });

        var source = new ol.source.WMTS(options);
        var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: source });

        //==========================
        // Initialize the map object
        //==========================
        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [ layer ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:27700',
                extent: [ -238375.0, 0.0, 900000.0, 1376256.0 ],
                resolutions: options.tileGrid.getResolutions(),
                minZoom: 0,
                maxZoom: 9,
                center: [ 337297, 503695 ],
                zoom: 9
            })
        });

        //===============
        //Add Point Layer
        //===============
        var layerPoint = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                id: 'point',
                features: [
                    //id: 'point',
                    new ol.Feature({
                        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([ 337297, 503695  ]))
                    })
                ]
            }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 12,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#38f'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff',
                        width: 6
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        map.addLayer(layerPoint);             
    });
```

Comment: If your coordinates [337297, 503695] are already in EPSG:27700 you do not need to call `fromLonLat`

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your response. I have tried several variations of geometry:  'geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([ 337297, 503695  ]))'
'geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([ -2.968, 54.425 ]))'
'geometry: new ol.geom.Point(337297, 503695)' However, none appear to work so either I'm doing this incorrectly or the fault lies somewhere else. Any ideas?

Comment: Point geometry coordinates should be passed as an array `new ol.geom.Point([337297, 503695])`

Comment: Thanks Mike. That did it. 'geometry: new ol.geom.Point([337297, 503695])' Should have noticed that last one myself. Going to have a bash at the route/line layer now.